# awk command with if and substring

Tags: if-statement, awk, sh, substr

I have an input file (input.txt) that looks like this:

```
    id01    90      5
    id01    80      4
    id01    79      3
    id13    95      5
    id01    77      3
    id01    85      4
    id15    92      5
    id17    99      5
    id18    65      2
    id19    72      3
```

And I want to output the file as in output.txt:

```
1    90      5
1    80      4
1    79      3
13   95      5
1    77      3
1    85      4
15   92      5
17   99      5
18   65      2
19   72      3
```

I did search and was able to find some code example that worked individually (like just the substring part, or just if part) but when I put the entire thing together I am getting syntax errors. I am doing this in ssh environment and I saw there is a slight difference in syntax between sh and bash. Below is what I was able to come up with but gives me syntax errors:

```
awk -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} { num = substr($1, 3, 1) if (num == "0") num2 = substr($1,4,1) else num2= substr($1,3,2)  {print num2, $2, $3 } }' input.txt > output.txt
```

I will appreciate any help on this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Some place you change `id01` to `1` and other to `01`, is this correct?

Comment: no, sorry, i updated the input file. It should just have 1 without the beginning 0s

Answer (score 1):

Some like this  `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/id/,"",$1);$1=$1+0}8' OFS="\t"
1       90      5
1       80      4
1       79      3
13      95      5
1       77      3
1       85      4
15      92      5
17      99      5
18      65      2
19      72      3
```

Updated to get rid of leading `0`

Comment: +1 for the approach but IMHO using an un-set variable `x` instead of a simple null string `""` obfuscates it. And if the poster wants to get rid of leading zeros it'd just need to do some math on $1: `{sub(/id/,"",$1);$1+=0}8`

Comment: OP is not clear if the `0` should go or not. I could have posted `awk '{sub(/id/,"",$1)} {print $0}'`

Comment: That's correct. Hence the `**if** the poster...`. Using `print $0` would do nothing that `8` doesn't do though.

Comment: Thanks Jotne, that works too. I am just wondering what is the main function of 8, just for my understanding. I tried to remove it and the result did not print so I am guessing it is related to printing but not 100% sure. Thanks.

Comment: In `awk` any number other than `0` means true.  And if some is true, do the default action, print.  So the `8` just means print the record.  `8` gives same action as `1`  and `1` = `1 {print}` = `1 {print $0}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this `sed`,

```
sed 's/id//g' file.txt
```

To get rid of the leading zeros,

```
sed 's/id0*//g' file.txt
```

Comment: +1 for a reasonable approach, and `sed 's/id0*//g'` to get rid of the leading zeros too if required.

Comment: Thanks Ed! This works perfect. Basically, the only thing left is the resulting file is not tab delimited as it was before, but I guess I can add this "awk -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS}" at the beginning and will work?

Comment: Hi Ed! Sorry, it works perfectly actually. The dummy file that I created to demonstrate my problem was not tab delimited that is why the output was not. Thanks again! I am not sure how I can accept this answer, the answer suggested by sat was partially incorrect but currently it is one selected as an answer.